# Are there 3-way water pipe junctions which allow any variant of flow?

Tags: plumbing

Suppose you have 3 pipes arriving at a junction: A, B & C
There are many possible water flows:

```
A => B+C
B => A+C
C => A+B
A+B => C
A+C => B
B+C => A
A => B (C not flowing)
A => C (B not flowing)
B => C (A not flowing)
B => A (C not flowing)
C => A (B not flowing)
C => B (A not flowing)
```

Obviously, given a fixed mains pressure and static valves *around* this junction, only one of these options can be happening *at a time*.
But by changing what valves are open around the joint, I could switch between these various options.

In particular, I have a design where A, B, and C are all sometimes an in-flow and sometimes an out-flow.

Question: **Do I need to get a "special" kind of 3 way joint for this?**

If I just get "[any old T-fitting](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/compression-fittings/3691659/?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Plumbing_%26_Pipeline_Whoop-_-Compression%20Fittings_Whoop-_-3691659&matchtype=&aud-828197004210:pla-301532857648&gclid=CjwKCAiA8ov_BRAoEiwAOZogwdVRzFFpdaYy_goBOYjp2mrQ3aucrgaPlk4ogQEa5EXTIvqRu1pa6xoC3pkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)" then will it handle *any* of these flow options, or are fittings "directional" in some way?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Asking for product recommendations is frowned upon here.   You might get better answers if you described your problem and goals.

Comment: I'm trying to get a direct answer to the straight forward question I've asked - do I need a special connector, to support these kinds of flow, or will "any old" connector do the job fine?

Comment: I agree with @George Anderson that, as written, this question does not fit the intent of the site because it does not correlate to Home Improvement. Also, it is an *XY Question*, wherein the real issue is obscured.

Comment: I'm not asking for a product recommendation - I'm entirely capable of finding a particular product, if I know that I need one. I'm trying to establish whether I need to look for a particular kind of connector?

Comment: I'm not sure why this wouldn't relate to Home Improvement? I'm desigining a piece of custom plumbing to Improve my Home's water system?

Comment: Why do you argue that it's an XY problem? Do you feel that the context of *why* I'm designing a flow system like this affects the answer to the question? I don't see why it would - this is a question of the physical properties of water flowing through pipes - it shouldn't care about why the water is flowing like that, should it?
If I ask a question about saw blades, it matters what the wood is, and what shapes and sizes I'm cutting ... not what I'm making with the wood once I've cut it?

Comment: XY because there is a problem you are trying to solve (that many smart people on here could probably help you with) but instead of describing the problem,you have already decided the answer is a particular thing; a theoretical "gizmo" that essentially does not exist in the world of domestic plumbing. Also, if this somehow relates to Home Improvement, you should edit the question to make that clear to readers.

Comment: I voted to close bc it's not really about home improvement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about home improvement.

Comment: `a theoretical "gizmo" that essentially does not exist in the world of domestic plumbing.` I assume you're asserting that `Jasen`'s answer is deeply and fundamentally wrong in some way, and that a standard T-Connection in some way *won't* work?

Comment: I also do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. Three pipes that have water which can flow any direction? HOW can the be?   In home plumbing, water generally flows in one direction, from source to fixture. Valves are open or closed, they do not know what direction the water is flowing.  *If you want people to help then it would in your best interest to provide as much info as you can and do not take a confrontational attitude when people ask for you to explain things better*. **If we do not understand what you understand then HELP us understand**.

Comment: This is the [definition of the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Basically, you're asking about how to accomplish the solution you've chosen, when that solution may not be particularly optimal, or even possible. If you explain your entire situation, someone may be able to help you solve it in a way you hadn't thought of that may be much A) easier, B) cost-effective, C) possible, D) code compliant, E) etc...

Comment: Can you explain how you suspect an ordinary t-fitting would not allow for any possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pressurized water or gas, any tee will work.

For gravity drains, each direction needs a different fitting.

Answer (score 2):

Get a 1-1/4" PVC T-fitting.  They're cheap.

Cast "Detect magic" on it.  There's no magic.  (magical T-fittings are NOT cheap).

Now look at the device itself with the Mark 1 eyeball and Fingers 1.0.

*Do you see anything special about that fitting?*

**No. There are no innards/guts which would provide any sort of flow checking.**  If you want, you can also examine a **check valve** to see an example of a piece which does have flow-management innards.

So a plain "tee" is "exactly what it says on the tin".  Flow will be decided by whatever is connected to it and how.

Comment: This was a lot of fun, but less actually useful than Jasen answer which clarifies that the critical difference is that pressurized water will flow in any direction and doesn't care about any "guiding" structures in the Tee